# How to allow resizing when the mouse hovers on the bottom of the image?

Tags: javascript, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I am using Draft.js plugin Resizeable.

I am trying to allow resizing when the mouse hovers on the bottom (if possible, also include bottom right corner) of the image.

In the [document](https://www.draft-js-plugins.com/plugin/resizeable) **Usage** section, it says:

> Hover with the mouse on the right side of the block and drag it to resize. At which edge resize is possible is configurable.

However, **Configuration Parameters** section is empty.

How can I use parameters in this function?

```
const resizeablePlugin = createResizeablePlugin();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this configuration is not specified in the documentation. But we can research the source code and we can notice that `createResizablePlugin` function receives this default configuration object:

```
{
  horizontal: 'relative',
  vertical: false,
  resizeSteps: 1
}
```

[image]

So we should override `vertical` property this way:

```
const resizeablePlugin = createResizeablePlugin({
  vertical: 'absolute', // <== ! override default value
});
```

After that we can resize by dragging bottom edge and bottom right corner.

Comment: Thanks! Add the [source code link](https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/blob/master/draft-js-resizeable-plugin/src/createDecorator.js) here for future people's convenience.